# Is updating an Answer problematic when it reflects changes in time?

Tags: discussion, support

I just updated [an answer suggesting an extension of a question that was looking for a how-to](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4888/4115).

The extension moved from *Magento-Hackathon* to *Firegento*, the official page shows this with no doubt and as I found the answer some days ago while looking for exactly this, I now went with the new version.

I therefore thought it's nice to update the answer to reflect the changes in time since answered.

However the edit got rejected in review: https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13951

Two times with the (hillarious!) reason

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

The original meaning of the post was to link the extension. The extension has been moved. The links have been updated with my edit. The original meaning was not lost but preserved (the edit actually also said *previously*).

Is this by intention or is the review on the Magento site of general such low quality? I hadn't had such issues earlier with edits.

Comment: That's the dice.